# create a folder in /storage/emulated/0

Tags: android, kotlin, android-file, android-storage

I  would like to create a directory in /storage/emulated/0/ and a save a file there.Since the "getExternalStorageDir()" & "getExternalPublicStorageDir()" are Depreciated I don't know how to implement it.
I have gone through most of the questions and answers but they are all either outdated/open.
All I want is a way to access the "storage/emulated/0/" path.

```
val extStorageDirectory = requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
val folder = File(extStorageDirectory, "Work Logs")
folder.mkdir()
```

The above code creates a folder in "Android/data/com.xxx.xxx/"

Comment: `The above code creates a folder in "Android/data/com.xxx.xxx/"` No. It creates a folder in `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxx.xxx/files`.

Comment: Deprecated will not say that you cannot use them. Use them! And adapt your code around mkdir().

Comment: yes sir I will edit that. I want it to be "/storage/emulated/0/Work Logs"

Comment: `Deprecated will not say that you cannot use them. Use them! And adapt your code around mkdir(). – blackapps 35 secs ago` sir when I tried using it the app crashed .

Comment: If your app crashes that you did not catch an exception that let your app crash. Catch it! And... you use mkdir in the wrong way. There all elend starts. Your app will not crash anymore if you handle mkdir in the right way. Solve it first!

Comment: ok I will look for it thank you

Comment: Is sir gender neutral? I'm not! ;-).

Comment: Madam? What makes you think so? Please post the used code first. Then post the logcat as text in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy with `MediaStore`.

```
binding.createFolderButton.setOnClickListener {
    val values = ContentValues()

    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "${Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS}/myFolder/")       //folder name

    contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), values)

    Toast.makeText(this, "\"myFolder\" created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

- Demo: https://youtu.be/a6Q7IlA_uOs